# Entity Framework with Multiple DB Engines

Tags: sql-server, oracle, db2, entity-framework-5

We have a few .Net application that we would like to start using Entity Framework 5.0 but the problem is that our customers can choose to use one of any of the following database engines:

- SQL Server (95% of Customers use this engine)
- Oracle (3% use this engine)
- DB2 (2%)

So as you can see an overwhelming majority of our customers use SQL Server. So my question is that assuming that each database engine will have the same exact schema layout then all we should have to do is to change the entity connection string to target each of these engine types, correct?

Sorry if this seems to be a simplistic question but I just wanted to make sure that I was on the right track here.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know Entity Framework, but the are many differences between the DB engines.

For example the security, in DB2 is always external (OS secutiry), in Oracle most of the time is internal. Procedure language is different, and I hope you don't use it for a multi-platform application.

The best is to try the execution with each database, and tune the procedure in order to work in all of them, but I think you have to do more that change the connection string.